# Puppet run failing because of missing facts on newly kickstarted machines

Tags: puppet

I have a Puppet fact called "location" that is located in /etc/puppet/modules/facter/lib/facter/extra_info.rb on the Puppetmaster.

Unfortunately the motd-module is failing on newly kickstarted machines with the error that the "location"-fact does not yet exist. This means that the Puppet agent run is quiting entirely, ergo not working.

How can I make the extra_info.rb be loaded first, so that the motd-module that depends on it, won't make Puppet quit it's run, because of missing facts?

Answer (score 1):

Have you added `pluginsync = true` in puppet.conf?

please refer http://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/configuring.html for facts configuration settings in puppet.conf.

Answer (score 0):

What does your class look like?

I would wrap the request for the fact with a conditional. This allows the class to process with the missing info and on a second run pull the fact as intended.